# How to run add_custom_command in cmakelist.txt file on the basis of configuration selected in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, cmakelists-options

I want to run

`add_custom_command(TARGET ProjectName  POST_BUILD COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory "SRC" "DEST" COMMENT "My Custom message")`

only when visual studio compiles the project in debug configuration. If the project is being compiled in Release mode then I dont want to copy this particular directory.
How do I implement such cases using cmake.

Comment: What worked for me is this:
`add_custom_command(TARGET ProjectName  POST_BUILD COMMAND "$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:${CMAKE_COMMAND};-E;copy_directory;\"SRC\";\"DEST\">" COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS COMMENT "My Custom message")`